# Another case of [singular/plural]?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, singular-vs-plural

Let us say there is a family of computer attacks known as DoS attacks.

If I want to describe a case of these attacks shall I use singular or plural?

> Another case of DoS [attack/attacks] is ...

Can you clarify this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are discussing **one** case so the subject of the clause is singular and therefore the verb must agree in number. It is just that simple.

> Another case of disruptive DoS attacks was ...

Ignoring relative clauses, the general rule is that a noun acting as the object of a preposition is not the subject of a verb. This is particularly easy to understand intuitively when, as here, the prepostional phrase can be deleted without loss of meaning. Given the context of discussing disruptive DoS attacks, you could say, without any loss of understandability,

> Another case was ...

Comment: Despite the fact that it was marked as answered. this does not answer the question that was asked at all. It wasn't asking about the verb, but if it should be the singular *attack* or the plural *attacks*. You've used the plural noun, which makes sense, but you haven't explained why. Instead, you've explained something quite different, and also discussed the wrong noun.